# Integral of analytic function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $D = \left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\left| Im(z) \right| < 1\right\}$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function with $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} f(z) = 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx < \infty$ . Show that for $\alpha \in (-1,1)$ $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+i\alpha) dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx.$$

Since I'm quite new to complex analysis, I don't quite know how to tackle this problem. I tried several things such as using parameterisations all of which led to nothing. Maybe there is someone to give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic in $D$, it follows from Cauchy's theorem that
$$ \int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\;dz=0 $$
for all $R>0$, where $\gamma_R$ is the rectangle with vertices $\pm R$, $\pm R+i\alpha$ (traversed counterclockwise, say).

Now use the condition $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$ to show that the integrals over the vertical sides tend to zero as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: @michael I've arrived at the result $$\int\limits_{-r}^r f(t) dt = \int\limits_{-r}^r f(-t+i\alpha) dt.$$ How do I get rid of the $-t$ in the second integral (because that's what I need to get the desired result)?

Comment: It should have worked out to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\;dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+i\alpha)\;dt$, but in any case if you make the subsititution $u=-t$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-t+i\alpha)\;dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u+i\alpha)\;du$.